Issue with DataformCreateWorkflowInvocationOperator in Google Cloud Composer
I'm currently working on a DAG in Google Cloud Composer that involves creating a workflow invocation using Dataform.
I'm following this documentation.
Here's the code snippet for my DAG:
with models.DAG(
    DAG_ID,
    schedule_interval=None,  # Override to match your needs
    start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,  # Override to match your needs
    tags=['dataform'],
) as dag:

    create_compilation_result = DataformCreateCompilationResultOperator(
        task_id="create_compilation_result",
        project_id=PROJECT_ID,
        region=REGION,
        repository_id=REPOSITORY_ID,
        compilation_result={
            "git_commitish": GIT_COMMITISH,
        },
    )

    create_workflow_invocation = DataformCreateWorkflowInvocationOperator(
        task_id='create_workflow_invocation',
        project_id=PROJECT_ID,
        region=REGION,
        repository_id=REPOSITORY_ID,
        workflow_invocation={
            "compilation_result": "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_compilation_result')['name'] }}",
            "invocation_config": { "included_tags": ["files"], "transitive_dependencies_included": True }
        },
    )

create_compilation_result >> create_workflow_invocation

However, when I run this DAG, I encounter the following error:
Failed to execute job 65 for task create_workflow_invocation (400 At least one action must be selected for execution.; 10747)

It seems like there is an issue with the configuration of the create_workflow_invocation task.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
